# An ImageView and TextView in a DrawerLayout with Xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I've been trying to bind data to a drawerlayout over the past few days with no luck. I think my issue is the binding of the data and making sure that I have the correct parameters in the right spot. The code is below. For the purposes of this code, I have an array of items that I load from Resources.Array.NavigationItems. Once I have this in a string array, I iterate through the list, create a dictionary with an item, which is the text to be displayed, and an image, which is the image that I want to display. At this time, the image is just load from my resources's drawables. I then create two arrays. These two arrays should map to the necessary from (data in the javalist) and to (the id of the controls to display. When I run the code below, I get the error shown below the code. I am assuming that I have something wrong with my dictionary definitions. Suggestions are appreciated.  Quite honestly, I'm not sure that I am creating the Dictionary or the List properly with the correct objects; my skills in translating from java to .net are probably lacking in this area.

```
_navigationItems = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.NavigationItems);

var mList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>(); 
for(int i=0;i<_navigationItems.Length;i++){
    var hm = new Dictionary<String,Object>();
    hm.Add("item", _navigationItems[i]);
    hm.Add("image", Resource.Drawable.aniswath);
    mList.Add(hm);
}
var fromH = new string[]{ "item", "image" };
var toH = new int[] { Resource.Id.title, Resource.Id.icon };

_drawerList.Adapter = new SimpleAdapter (this, mList, 
Resource.Layout.custom_drawer_item, fromH, toH);
```

Here are the contents of my Resource/Layout/custom_drawer_item.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aniswath" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error message determined from monitor:

```
04-11 21:40:50.022: E/AndroidRuntime(2515): java.lang.ClassCastException: mono.android.runtime.JavaObject cannot be cast to java.util.Map
04-11 21:40:50.022: E/AndroidRuntime(2515): at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:147)
04-11 21:40:50.022: E/AndroidRuntime(2515): at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
```

Comment: You are probably better off making your own `Adapter` instead of using `SimpleAdapter`. Saves you the headache of wrapping stuff in `Java.Lang.Object`.

Comment: Thanks Cheesebaron.  I had been given someone else's code.  I could never figure out why it wouldn't work properly.  Based on your suggestion, I rewrote this in a few minutes this morning, and it just worked.  Thanks for the suggestion to get me on the right path.  :-)

Comment: And thanks for the suggested changes/edits to those that made them.  :-)